# Find and Count string Using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, regex

I want to find the number of II, III, I, D, F and CP in the following table using Jquery. Firstly, I was thinking of using Regular Expression but it didn't work for me. I am just a beginner and this is what I have tried so far.

Table:

```
<table>
   <tr>
     <th>Sl</th>
     <th>Name</th>
     <th>status</th>
     <th>position</th>
   </tr>
   <?php while($row= $dbh->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
   <tr>
     <td><?php echo $row['id'];?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['nm'];?></td>
     <td class="st"><?php echo $row['st'];?></td>//Regular AND private
     <td class="ps"><?php echo $row['ps'];?></td>//output-CP, I, II, III, D, F
   </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

Jquery:

```
var ps = $('.ps').text();//output is IIIIIIDIIIICPIIIIIIDIICPIIFIIII
var compt = ps.match(/CP+/g);
$(".inbody").text(compt.length);//This give me the number of CP i.e. 2
```

I want the ps value `(IIIIIIDIIIICPIIIIIIDIICPIIFIIII)` in this format:

```
II, I,III,D,III,I,CP,III,I,I,I,D,II,CP,II,F,I,III
```

so that I can count them separately like below (or please suggest better way):

```
var arr = ps.split(",");
var cp = $.inArray("CP",arr).length; //will output 2
var Ist = $.inArray("I",arr).length;//will output 6
var Snd = $.inArray("II",arr).length;//will output 3
var Trd = $.inArray("III",arr).length;//will output 4
var Dnt = $.inArray("D",arr).length;//will output 2
var Fld = $.inArray("F",arr).length;//will output 1
```

So My question is: how can I get formatted data like this `II, I,III,D,III,I,CP,III,I,I,I,D,II,CP,II,F,I,III` from my table using jquery. I want to find the number of CP position in Regular and Private status seperately as well. Please help me.

Comment: Stop using deprecated `mysql_*` function, use PDO / MySQLi instead. And using PHP short tags may lead to compatibility issue. Try to avoid them

Comment: @Raptor, Yes, please. I know. But this is not going to help me as my question is just jquery, not the php part.

Comment: @LalhriatpuiiMapuii post the generated HTML and not the server side code as this question is about jQuery/JS.

Comment: @Raptor, thanks for your concern. I have changed it to pdo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`jQuery.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/):

```
var texts = $.map($('.ps'), function(el) { return $(el).text(); }); 
console.log(texts);
```

outputs: `["II", "I", "III", "D", "III", "CP"]`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4w7yeawx/)

So if you want to have arrays based on the previous `.st` row you could do:

```
var texts_private = $.map($('td.st:contains("Private") + td'), function (el) {
    return $(el).text();
});
var texts_regular = $.map($('td.st:contains("Regular") + td'), function (el) {
    return $(el).text();
});
console.log(texts_private, texts_regular);
```

It will grab the `.st` row, looks what text is inside with `:contains()` and than looks at the next row.

The functionality will get you two arrays:

```
["I", "D", "CP"] ["II", "III", "III"]
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4w7yeawx/3/)

Comment: Thanks for your attempt. How can I get the number of CP's in private and regular status seperately?

Comment: This will give you the output you wanted, but just not regular / private seperate. How do you know something is regular or private?

Comment: thanks. from `td class="st"`, private or regular status will be generated by the php code. so `st.text()` will determine that. Please help me. Please see the fiddlehttp://jsfiddle.net/4w7yeawx/1/

Comment: So every `.ps` will have a `.st` before it. And you want to have an array based on that value?